# Application crash when try to create session

Tags: ios, quickblox

I am developing application for video chat and want to integrate Quickblox with my application, but application is crash when try to create session with following error message.

```
2014-12-23 09:57:47.030 closeChat[3758:60b] +[QBRequest createSessionWithExtendedParameters:successBlock:errorBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x199f74
2014-12-23 09:57:47.036 closeChat[3758:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[QBRequest createSessionWithExtendedParameters:successBlock:errorBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x199f74'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x30862f83 0x3b013ccf 0x30866823 0x30865203 0x307b4768 0x35377 0x330844ab 0x33084269 0x330fb505 0x330f9e85 0x330f99d3 0x330f995b 0x330f98f3 0x330f1f69 0x33086107 0x330f9641 0x330f9105 0x3308b045 0x33088827 0x330f233d 0x330eefad 0x330e956b 0x330856e9 0x33084851 0x330e8ca9 0x3569daed 0x3569d6d7 0x3082da67 0x3082da03 0x3082c1d7 0x30796ebf 0x30796ca3 0x330e7ed1 0x330e314d 0x4a14d 0x3b520ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I used follwowing code..

```
QBSessionParameters *parameters = [QBSessionParameters new];
parameters.userLogin = @"email@domain";
parameters.userPassword = @"password";

// QuickBlox session creation
[QBRequest createSessionWithExtendedParameters:parameters successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBASession *session)
{
    [self loginToChat:session];

} errorBlock:[self handleError]];
```

please help to solve this error, thanks.

Comment: still not, i got same error.

Comment: Have you got this resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Try with creating `QBUser` inside the `successBlock`:

```
// QuickBlox session creation 
[QBRequest createSessionWithExtendedParameters:parameters successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBASession *session) { 

   // create a QBUser
   QBUUser *user = [QBUUser user]; 
   user.ID = session.userID; 
   user.password = your password; 
   // Login to QuickBlox Chat 
   [[QBChat instance] loginWithUser:user];     
} errorBlock:[self handleError]];
```

Also what is there in `handleError` method you have not mentioned that in question description.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue - the probem is that the function +[QBRequest createSessionWithExtendedParameters:successBlock:errorBlock:] is not defined in the class QBRequest, but in one of it's categories (QBRequest+QBAuth).

This is a known problem and can be solved by adding "-ObjC" to your "Other Linker Flags" build setting:

1. In Xcode, choose View > Navigators > Show Project Navigator, or press ⌘1.
2. Select your project under the PROJECT heading in the Project Navigator, then select the Build Settings tab.
3. Scroll down to the Other Linker Flags build setting under the Linking collection, or type "Other Linker Flags" into the search bar.
4. Set the value of the Other Linker Flags build setting to $(OTHER_LDFLAGS) -ObjC.

See [this Technical Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1490/_index.html) for more details.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - but adding "-ObjC" to the "Other Linker Flags" build setting is the essential part of the answer - or is it not? As a new member here (after long years of reading answers - this is my first provided answer), i'm happy for any hints to improve my answers

Comment: You need not copy all contents inside the link. Just add that part which solves the problem. Just make this answer the highlight of whats inside the link so that when the link is removed, or moved to another one, this will still stand on its own.

Answer (score 1):

My issue got solved when i added -ObjC in other linker flags.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i had he same issue once. Foolishly the reason turned out to be i was not setting the API keys before creating the session.